# Oracle 11g http listener configuration for PL/SQL server pages

Tags: oracle

Could please someone point me how to configure oracle db to be able to display PL/SQL Server pages. I have successfully created and mapped dad with the `DBMS_EPG`.

Here is the listener:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Ja\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 8080))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\app\Ja
```

When I want to enter

> localhost:8080/my_dad/home

I get error: No data received.

How do I solve this?

Comment: are you aware about APEX? listener does answer in HTTP. You have to configure APEX services.

Answer (score -1):

check tnsnames.ora file

C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\Oracle\NETWORK\ADMIN

ORCL= 
   (DESCRIPTION = 
       (ADDRESS_LIST = 
             (ADDRESS = 
                  (PROTOCAL = TCP)
                  (HOST = 123.456.789.123)
                  (PORT = 1521)
             )
       )
       (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ORCL))
   )

Comment: -1 a webserver will not use tnsnames ora. This port configured on 1521 is intended for Oracle clients